# ¿Por que se cicla la funcion?

Tags: python, funciones

Tengo una función "ecuaciones_3()" la cual tiene que terminar cuando muestra los valores ingresados, pero vuelve a iniciar el proceso, según se con el "return" de una variable marca el final de la función, pero en mi caso no rompe el ciclo.

uso "done" en el return a modo de validador, se que no es lo idóneo, pero fue lo que se me ocurrió para hacerlo, también tengo el problema con mis validaciones donde estoy comparando "signoX" con "-" y "+" si es diferente de uno u otro tiene que devolver un mensaje de error, dado que sea cual sea la situación me devuelve el error y no me permite ingresar los valores.

```
def ecuaciones_3():
    print("Termino 1,  Ec 1 : \n")
    print("¿Es + o - ?\n")
    signo1 = input()
    if signo1 != '-' or signo1 != '+':
        print("Dato incorrecto vuelva a intentar")
    else:
        if signo1 == '-':
            print("Ingrese el valor1 del primer termino:  \n")
            v1 = float(input())
        else:
            print("Ingrese el Valor1 del primer termino: \n")
            v1 = float(input())
    print("Termino 2,  Ec 1 : \n")
    print("¿Es + o - ?\n")
    signo2 = input()
    if signo2 != '-' or signo2 != '+':
        print("Dato incorrecto vuelva a intentar")
    else:
        if signo2 == '-':
            print("Ingrese el Valor2 del Segundo termino : \n")
            v2 = float(input())
        else:
            print("Ingrese el Valor2 del Segundo termino : \n")
            v2 = float(input())
    print("Termino 3, Ec 1 : \n")
    print("¿Es + o - ?")
    signo3 = input()
    if signo3 != '-' or signo3 != '+':
        print("Dato incorrecto vuelva a intentar")
    else:
        if signo3 == '-':
            print("Ingrese el Valor3 del Tercer termino : \n")
            v3 = float(input())
        else:
            print("Ingrese el Valor3 del Tercer termino : \n")
            v3 = float(input())
    print("Ingrese el resultado o Valor absoluto: \n")
    va1 = float(input())
    print(signo1, v1, signo2, v2, signo3, v3, "=", va1)
    return 'done'


print("Menu: \n")
print("\t1- Ingresar ecuaciones (x3): \n\t2- Ingresar # de Decimales\n\t3- Ingresar % de Error \n\t4- 
    Operar (paso1)\n\t5- Error (paso2)\n\t opcion: ")
opc = int(input())
if opc == 1:
   comp = ecuaciones_3()
   if comp == 'done':
       print("Se guardo la ecuacion correctamente!!!\n")
   else:
       print("Ocurrio un error!!!\n")
else:
   print("hasta aqui esta!!!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que has usado un `or` donde debía ser un `and`:

```
 if signo1 != '-' or signo1 != '+':
```

Al usar `or` siempre se va a cumplir la condición, ya que si pones `+`, entonces será distinto de `-`, pero si pones `-` entonces será distinto de `+`. Una de las do siempre será cierta. Pero solo si es distinto de **ambos** (`and`) deberías rechazar ese input.

Es bastante habitual confundirse en este tipo de comparaciones, por lo que yo te recomiendo que hagas algo como `if signo1 not in ["+", "-"]` que en mi opinión es menos equívoco.

### Bonus

Aprovecho para comentarte algunas cosas mejorables en tu código, por si son de tu interés.

- Cuando el usuario introduce mal el `signo1`, por ejemplo, el programa le dice que está mal, pero *aún así* continúa y le pide el `signo2`. Lo habitual sería que continuara preguntándole por `signo1` hasta recibir una entrada válida. Esto puede lograrse con un bucle `while`.
- El código de la función, como habrás podido observar, es muy repetitivo. El código que pide cada uno de los signos y de los valores es exactamente el mismo, sólo que cambia la variable en la que lo va metiendo y ligeramente el mensaje al usuario para indicarle qué término o valor está introduciendo.

  Este tipo de código tan repetitivo es síntoma claro de que puede (y debe) usarse un bucle para hacer esas repeticiones, en lugar de copiar una y otra vez las mismas instrucciones.

  El bucle se repetiría 3 veces, una para cada término. Se puede tener una variable que vaya tomando los valores 1, 2, 3 para generar los mensajes apropiados con respecto a qué término se está pidiendo.

  En lugar de tres variables `signo1`, `signo2`, `signo3` (y otras tantas para los valores), se pueden usar listas. Las listas permiten ir añadiendo elementos para después iterar por ellos.

Haciendo uso de estas ideas el código se podría reescribir en la forma siguiente, que como ves es más corta. No obstante hace uso de listas, que quizás es un concepto que aún no tenías, de un diccionario para traducir números en palabras (1 es "primer", 2 es "segundo", etc) y de cosas como `zip()` para emparejar elementos de listas diferentes. Te invito a estudiar este código y preguntar lo que no te quede claro.

```
def ecuaciones_3():
  ordinal = { 1: "primer", 2: "segundo", 3: "tercer"}
  signos = []
  valores = []

  for t in [1,2,3]:                       # Bucle que se repite para cada termino
    print(f"Termino {t}, Ec 1:\n")
    print("¿Es + o - ?\n")
    signo = input()
    while signo not in ["+", "-"]:        # Bucle para volver a preguntar hasta que esté bien
        print("Dato incorrecto vuelva a intentar")
        signo = input()
    # Añadir el signo a la lista de signos
    signos.append(signo)

    # Y el valor a la lista de valores
    print(f"Ingrese el valor{t} del {ordinal[t]} termino:\n")
    valor = float(input())
    valores.append(valores)

  # Una vez introducidos los tres términos
  print("Ingrese el resultado o Valor absoluto: \n")
  result = float(input())

  # Imprimir cada término con su signo
  for s,v in zip(signos, valores):
    print(s,v, end=" ")
  print( "=", resultado)     # Imprimir resultado
  return "done"
```